# How to get name of random .jpg in folder? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dear stackoverflow community, I have the following problem. I tried to select a random image from my 'uploads' folder. With this line of code:

```
upload = random.choice(os.listdir("/bot/upload/"))
```

And I want to upload the image (the .jpg) via this line with InstaBot.

```
bot.upload_photo(upload,caption="Caption.")
```

The way I interpret my own code, the name of a random .jpg file is "passed" to the variable 'upload'. And then it should be uploaded. This is in the documentation:

```
bot.upload_photo("post.jpg",caption="Caption.")
```

When I try this with the variable (upload) I keep getting this error:

```
with open(fname, "rb") as fhandle:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'post.jpg'
```

What I don't understand is that I didn't specify 'post.jpg'. I only used the variable and let the file name be output. So my script finds the file but says itself that it doesn't exist?!
What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me please? Best wishes.

Comment: You should add directory path to filename `open("/bot/upload/" + fname, "rb")` or better to use specific function `open(os.path.join("/bot/upload/", fname), "rb")`

Comment: Alternatively, since you want to limit to `.jpg` files, you may as well replace `os.listdir("/bot/upload/")` with `glob.glob("/bot/upload/*.jpg")`; that will both include the whole path (`glob` returns qualified paths) and filter to only files with the `.jpg` extension.